# How can I know in Python how many times a line of code is executed per minute?

Tags: python, loops, time

For example if I have:

```
 something=something+1
```

I want to know how many times in a minute, this line is executed in order to create another variable with this result?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to do some basic benchmarking, in this case it would go like this:

```
import time
start = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

something = 0

while something < 1000000:
    something = something + 1

delta = int(round(time.time() * 1000)) - start

print "loop ran 1000000 times in {0:0d} milliseconds".format(delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to wait a full minute (which usually is not the case) you could do something like

```
import time
start = time.time()

operationsPerMinute = 0

while (time.time() - start < 60):
    operationsPerMinute = operationsPerMinute + 1

print(operationsPerMinute)
```

In which case operationsPerMinute holds the value you want.

Alternatively, you could run in a much smaller time frame and use a bit of math to estimate it in a whole minute time frame.

Answer (score 0):

For benchmarking you would probably ask for per second timings.

To count events in the last minute, here is a class remembering event timestamps for a given period:

```
import bisect
import time

class TimedCounter:
    def __init__(self, period=60.0):
        self._timestamps = []
        self._period = period

    def _cleanup(self, now):
        del self._timestamps[:bisect.bisect_left(self._timestamps, now - self._period)]

    def increment(self):
        now = time.time()
        self._timestamps.append(now)
        self._cleanup(now)   # optimization: not necessary to call every time

    def get_count(self):
        self._cleanup(time.time())
        return len(self._timestamps)
```

and an example:

```
tc = TimedCounter(1.0)
for i in range(7, 27):
    tc.increment()
    print("{} time(s) in the last second".format(tc.get_count()))
    time.sleep(7/i)
```